# Typing multiple line commands in the Terminal

Tags: command-line

I know that I can copy paste this command in my terminal, but how do I type this?

```
make ex1
cc ex1.c -o ex1
```

Typing it all on one line produces the following:

```
make: Nothing to be done for ex1.
make: *** No rule to make target cc.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should type only `make ex1` do not add `cc ex1.c -o ex1` , `make` will run that command.

If you are getting `make: Nothing to be done for ex1` error means you already have a ex1 compiled file in your directory where ex1.c is present. You need to delete/move/rename that file because `make` will try to create file named `ex1` (same name) if file with same name is already there it gives error. That why its giving error.

You can use directly `cc filename.c -o filename(anyname)` which is the same.

Comment: Ah I see now, the second line is a product of the command. I was following a tutorial and the directions weren't clear.